# Finite groups $G$ such that every Galois extension of group $G$ is totally real

Tags: nt.number-theory, galois-theory

This is an extended repost of the [following question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4368460/finite-groups-g-such-that-every-galois-extension-of-group-g-is-totally-real) asked on MSE two weeks ago.

I was playing with Galois extensions of small degree while preparing the final exam for my course in Galois theory, when the following question came up:

Can we characterize the finite groups $G$ such that every Galois extension $L/\mathbb{Q}$ with Galois group $G$ is totally real ?

**Example.** Every finite group $G$ with **odd** order satisfies this condition: if $\alpha$ is a primitive element of $L/\mathbb{Q}$, its minimal polynomial $f$ has odd degree, so it has a real root $\beta$. Now $\beta$ is also a primitive element of $L$, that is $K=\mathbb{Q}(\beta)$. Now, since $L$ is Galois it contains all the roots of $f$, so all the roots of $f$ are real.

Note that the same result holds if we replace $\mathbb{Q}$ by a real number field $K$.

I don't know any example of group having even-order satisfying the required property.
Even better, I can prove the following theorem.

**Thm.** Let $K$ be a real number field (i.e. a number field which is a subfield of $\mathbb{R}$). There is no nontrivial $2$-group $G$ such that every Galois extension $L/K$ with Galois group $G$ is totally real.

**Proof.** Let $G$ be a non trivial $2$-group, and let $L/K$ be a Galois extension of group $G$. If $L/K$ is totally complex, we are done. Otherwise, $L/K$ is totally real. Let $\tau\in G$ be a central element of $G$ of order $2$, and let $M=L^\tau=L(\sqrt{\alpha})$.

Since $L$ is real, $\alpha>0$.

Note that $M/K$ is Galois since $\langle \tau\rangle\triangleleft G$.
Now, let $t\in K$ such that $t<0$. Since $t<0$ and $L$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{R}$, $L/K$ and $K(\sqrt{t})/K$ are linearly disjoint (since these extensions are Galois with "trivial" intersection). Hence $E=L(\sqrt{t})=M(\sqrt{\alpha},\sqrt{t})$ is Galois over $K$, and we have a canonical isomorphism $Gal(E/K)\simeq Gal(L/K)\times Gal(K(\sqrt{t})/K)$, given by restrictions.

Let $\rho\in Gal(E/K)$ be the preimage of $(\tau, *)$ via this isomorphism, where $*$ is complex conjugation.
Since $\tau$ is central, $\langle\rho\rangle\triangleleft Gal(E/K)$ and $E^\rho/K$ is Galois.

By definition, $\rho(\sqrt{\alpha})= -\sqrt{\alpha}, \rho(\sqrt{t})=-\sqrt{t})$ and $\rho_M=Id_M$.

Since $\rho$ has order $2$, $[E:E^\rho]=2$. Now $M(\sqrt{t\alpha})\subset E^\rho$ and by degree considerations, we get that $E^\rho=M(\sqrt{t\alpha})$. Since $t<0$ and $\alpha<0$, $E^\rho/K$ is then totally complex.

It remains to show that $G'=Gal(E^\rho/K)$ is isomorphic to $G$. For $\sigma\in G$, let $\varphi(\sigma)\in G'$ such that $\varphi_M=\sigma_M, \varphi(\sqrt{\alpha})=-\sqrt{\alpha}$ and $\varphi(\sqrt{t})=-\sqrt{t}$.

Then $\varphi(\sigma)$ is uniquely defined by the conditions above, and $\varphi$ is an isomorphism.$\square$

Hence, I propose the following conjecture.

**Conjecture.** Let $K$ be a real number field (maybe totally real??) Let $G$ be a finite group.  Then every Galois extension $L/K$ of group $G$ is totally real if and only if $G$ has odd order.

The main problem of the proof above is that it does not generalize to groups of even order: such a group does not necessairly have a central element of order $2$. We could of course try the following:
Let $L/K$ be a totally real extension with Galois group $G$, where $G$ has even order.

Let $S$ be a $2$-Sylow subgroup of $G$, and let $K'=L^S$, so $[K':K]$ is odd (but not necessarily Galois...).
Writing $L=M(\sqrt{\alpha})$, one may pick any $t\in K'$ or even in $K$, $t<0$, and $M(\sqrt{t\alpha})/K'$ would be a totally complex Galois extension of group $S$.

I don't see any reason why we could choose $t$ is such a way that $M(\sqrt{t\alpha})/K$ is still Galois with group $G$.

Hence (finally) my question.

**Question.** Is my conjecture true ? If necessary, one may assume that $K=\mathbb{Q}$.

I am happy to assume the the Galois inverse conjecture is true, so we don't have to care about the existence of Galois extensions $L/\mathbb{Q}$ of given group $G$.

Comment: It seems to me that your MSE question already received a reasonably good answer: 1) the conjecture is true conditional on "Inverse Galois Problem with prescribed signature". 2) The latter however probably does not follow in obvious way from mere IGP (whereas "totally real IGP" famously does). 3) There are at least no "local obstructions" to the conjecture.  I doubt much more can be said, unless you're explicitly looking for smallest-possible strengthenings of IGP which do imply "IGP with signature".

Comment: @Laurent Moret-Bailly: How does that disprove the conjecture? I thought existence of totally imaginary extension for even order groups is just what the OP wants (of course ideally without extending the base field) , no?

Comment: @JoachimKönig: Oops, I misread the question! Thanks.